# How to filter the record in blaze where id is equal to the specified id?

Tags: blaze

I am using blaze for querying data from csv and json. I just need to query a record where id is equal to the specified id? Is it possible.

```
city = city[city.ID = 1]
```

While trying to execute the above code it shows
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That works, but in your case you'd need to have a field named `ID`, it's not a magical field. The following works, but only because there's a column explicitly named `id` in `accounts.csv`:

```
from blaze import Data
from blaze.utils import example

accounts = Data(example('accounts.csv')
accounts[accounts.id == 2]
#    id  name  balance
# 1   2   Bob      200
```